# How to separate each value for each textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It seems that when I try to retrieve a data for a certain id it populates it's data to all textbox present.

Here is my addrow script that adds a new row of textboxes:

```
function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;

        }
    }
```

Here is my html file

```
 <td><input type="text" name="personId" class="personId" size="30" onchange="test()"/></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="personName" class="personName" size="30" disabled/></td>
```

Here is the test script which appends that data to the textbox:

```
 function test(){

var $cell = $('.personId');              
var cellData = $cell.html();
$cell.data('value', cellData);

//Code here to pass the personId in to an ajax and return it's corresponding personName

 success:   function(data) {

    $('.personName').val(data.person);

 }
}
```

What happens is that when I have 3 rows of personId and personName and I enter one personId all the textboxes in the 3 rows returns the personName. The goal is that when I enter an personId in one row pesonName should only reflect on the textbox i'm currently entering the personId. Please help. Thank you so much.

Comment: It is because in ajax success function you are assigning person name using class selector `$('.personName').val(data.person);`. You should use Id selector to assign person name.

Comment: I understand but the how I guess my question was a bit vague how about having dynamic textboxes?

Comment: Generate dynamic Id. Can you create Jsfiddle?

Comment: i apologize i might need your help to generate the dynamic id. I could provide you a jfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/tLbj36er/

Comment: Can u add addRow code also?

Comment: show me code to add row to table code in JsFiddle. So that I can change it.

Comment: Hello just added it in JsFiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tLbj36er/4/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127881/discussion-between-abpatil-and-newbph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the comments for understanding code.

```js
var personVal =1; //personVal to create dynamic id

$(document).on('keyup','.personId', function() {
   var personId = $(this).val();
   
   //Code here to pass the personId to an ajax and return it's corresponding personName
   //ajax success code here
   //and success code like
   // success: function(data) {            
       var currentPersonVal=this.id.split('-')[1];
       var personName="#personName-"+currentPersonVal;
       $(personName).val(currentPersonVal);//name hardcoded for your understanding, you need to add 'data.person'              
   //}
});

function addRow(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        personVal =personVal+1 //increase personVal by 1
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        //generate textbox here with dynamic id by adding personVal at the end of id and '-'(dash) is used to split id later 
        var newcell = row.insertCell(0);
        newcell.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='personId-"+personVal+"' class='personId' size='30' />";
        var newcell = row.insertCell(1);
        newcell.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='personName-"+personVal+"' class='personName' size='30' disabled/>";

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table align="center" width="100%" id="table1Id" class = "centerAlign">
    <td><input type="text" id="personId-1" class="personId" size="30" /></td> 
    <td><input type="text" id="personName-1" class="personName" size="30" disabled/></td>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('table1Id');"/>
```

Let me know if you don't understand anything.

Comment: Having an error on this line of code  var currentPersonVal=this.id.split('-')[1]; returns Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @Newbph check HTML table, for first two default text boxes I have changed name as per our naming convention. If this does not solve your problem please make JSFiddle so that I can take a look what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can give personId by data attribute like :

```
<td><input type="text" name="personId" data-personId = "1" class="personId" size="30" onchange="test()"/></td>
```

And then after that you can get that personId in like :

```
$('.personId').attr('data-personId');
```

Comment: How can you do this dynamically? I have included my addRow where it adds the textboxes.

Comment: Near every cell, you have to give data-personId : newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;

Answer (score 0):

In your html file change test() to test(this):

```
  <td><input type="text" name="personId" data-personId = "1" class="personId" size="30" onchange="test()"/></td>
```

& change your test function to this :

```
       function test(e){

           // remove this 
           // var $cell = $('.personId');              
            var cellData = $(e).html();
            $(e).data('value', cellData);

            //Code here to pass the personId in to an ajax and return it's corresponding personName

            success:   function(data) {

              $(e).closest('.personName').val(data.person);

     }
    }
```

Comment: Hello it's partially correct but I failed to include that the second textbox should be the one changing depending on the value of personId. Please check I have included the other textbox. Thanks.

Comment: @Newbph check now

Comment: What you are expecting from  $cell.html(); ? Since its an input tag it will not have any html. I'm guessing that you want to set the data-value of "personId " textbox as a value of  personName

Comment: I did try and it seems there is no need for that code. What could yyou suggest?

Comment: if there is no use of it, you should remove it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127877/discussion-between-newbph-and-hitesh-jangid).